# Remove/Change mention of disclosure in spam flag reason

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307955/blatantly-offtopic-spam-that-discloses-affiliation).

I think we should change the description of the spam flag to either make it clearer that disclosure isn't required, or remove that part of the description altogether.

From the answers to my previous question, it doesn't appear as though disclosure is really that relevant to whether or not it should be flagged:

- Journeyman Geek: "If its off topic and spam, it needs to go away, even with full disclosure."
- ɪʙᴜɢ: "Those blatant spam do not need to "have no disclosure"."

So why mention it at all then? I can't suggest what it should be changed to, as I might be missing the point of mentioning it at all, but it's not exceedingly clear in it's current state.

---

Maybe add an "or" in there to make it clear that *either* condition is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

> I think we should change the description of the flag reason to either make it clearer that disclosure isn't required, or remove that part of the description altogether.

There are two types of spam:

- Something that is relevant to the question, answer and within the scope of the site, but without affiliation disclosure (consider for example a kitchen equipment store that posts a relevant answer on Seasoned Advice, and explains there is a special device to do the trick and company X sells it: it is spam if the author did not disclose they are related to company X);
- Totally irrelevant, off-topic advertisements.

Both should be flagged as spam. It is hard to make a short text that covers both. The important thing here is: the first category is harder to diagnose that the second. The second one is clearly irrelevant, and if not for spam, it would have been flagged for numerous other reasons.

The text is now written to carefully explain both options, although you should read the comma correctly.

- It "Exists **only** to promote a product or service";

*or*

- "does **not disclose** the author's affiliation"

The current text is fine to me.

Comment: I think the problem may be that I read the comma as "and". Without any other indication, "and" being implicit strikes me as more likely than "or".

Comment: Then replace the comma with "or".

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: I wonder how often spam flags on the first kind of posts (relevant but lacking disclosure) are actually actioned. IME, they seem to get declined pretty often, either because the moderator handling them doesn't spot the undisclosed affiliation, or because they do but consider the 100 rep penalty disproportionate for something that might have been posted in good faith and could be fixed by adding a simple notice about the poster's affiliation. Personally, I nowadays much prefer to use custom moderator flags for any non-obvious (or not obviously bad-faith) cases of undisclosed self-promotion.

Answer (score 1):

I think an important thing here is the "common sense rule".

More or less, if it's clearly spam, it's clearly spam, even if it meets the letter of the other criteria such as disclosure. The big difference comes down to how we *eventually* deal with it.

A good chunk of spam really *should* die (quickly and with minimal fuss). - it's blatantly off topic, machine generated and simply doesn't work with our *decor*. We nuke em from orbit. Then sometimes nuke em again cause they won't stay gone.

*Sometimes* actual people ... mess up. They find this lovely site and go "Hey, I am working on this cool thing, I'll keep posting answers on it!". In these cases *sometimes* we can send them a mod message and get them to see the error of their ways.

Ideally we shouldn't see the former (user nuked to d00m). We should see the latter, or at the very least they'll either go away cause they can't post, or complain on meta.

Which is why I always use the phrase necessary (disclosure is *essential*) but isn't good enough in many cases.

The *exact* wording matters less than the discretion of the flaggers. It's *guidance* but with time, folks usually work out what to do.